# Create records with two related models using mixins

Tags: typescript, next.js, sequelize.js, one-to-many, mixins

I want to create order items using two related models, "Product" and "Order". Both order and product have many order items. An order item belongs to both product and order (one-to-many relation).

Right now, I am using the mixin from the order model to create an order item, giving it the "product_id". I can also use the mixin from the product model to create an order item, giving it the "order_id" like this:

```
  product.createOrderItem({
    order_id: order.id,
    quantity,
    amount: product?.price * quantity,
    currency: 'SAR'
  });
```

But can I use both of the relations(mixins from both models) to create order items? Here is what I have done so far:

```
  const order = await user?.createOrder({
    status: 'Processing',
    source: 'manual'
  });

  const orderItemsPromises = products?.map(async ({ productId, quantity }) => {
    const product = await Product.findByPk(productId);

    if (product) {
      return order.createOrderItem({
        local_product_id: product.id,
        quantity,
        amount: product?.price * quantity,
        currency: 'SAR'
      });
    }

    return null;
  });
```

Comment: Can't get what are you trying to achieve? Could you show an example of possible code you want to get? For me it doesn't look logical to create order items from products, only from an order itself because it owns order items in the first place

Comment: Look, an order item has two foreign keys: i) order_id ii) product_id. Now, I want to create order item using both of these related models. Right now, I am using mixin from Order model to create an order item. But I can also use mixin from the product model to create order item. I want to use both.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want to pass `product` instead of `product.id` in `createOrderItem`?

Comment: I can also do something like `product.createOrderItem`, but then I would need to pass the `order_id`. Can I create order items neither giving `order_id` nor `product_id`?

Comment: Seems like no. Even if you try to use `orderItem.create` you still need to indicate ids